# How to get all data in the table with hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

```
public Service getServiceData(){
    return (Service)ServiceDaoImpl.getSession().get(Service.class, new Integer(1));
}
```

The get method is getting one.
I want to get all data for the jsp page.

Comment: Can you show me the link or the example?

Answer (score 17):

With the Hibernate 5 the `createCriteria` is deprecated use something like this

```
private static <T> List<T> loadAllData(Class<T> type, Session session) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(type);
    criteria.from(type);
    List<T> data = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    return data;
  }
```

usage

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
List<User> users = loadAllData(User.class, session);
```

Comment: With the Hibernate 5 the `createCriteria` is deprecated. Use @Babu's solution. This generic method is well-written

Answer (score 10):

Try below piece of code and replace Entity with your Entity class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")      
public List<Entity> getAlldata(){       
    try
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Entity.class).list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're returning Entity but your method signature claims your function will return a List<Entity>  - as is this will not compile. I think you meant to "return list;"

Answer (score 8):

Try as  following to get all rows from table

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Service> Service getServiceData() {

         return ServiceDaoImpl.getSession().createQuery("from Service").list(); 
    }
```

Comment: `ServiceDaoImpl.getSession().createQuery("from Service").list()` as per the question. Also the query can be `select S from Service S`. Both query is correct.

Comment: You can remove `session.close();` too, if you are using spring transaction management using `@Transactional` or xml.

Comment: error:Type mismatch: cannot convert from Service to List<Service>

Comment: This method returns List, at method calling use List<Service> list=ServiceDaoImpl.getServiceData() and iterate this list

Answer (score 5):

Since `List<Entity> list = session.createCriteria(Entity.class).list();`
was deprecated,

You can use  `CriteriaBuilder()`.

```
        try ( Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            // Create CriteriaBuilder
            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

            // Create CriteriaQuery
            CriteriaQuery<Entity> criteria = builder.createQuery(Entity.class);

            // Specify criteria root
            criteria.from(Entity.class);

            // Execute query
            List<Entity> entityList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

            for (Entity e : entityList) {
             // load the data
            }
        }
```

Click [here](https://github.com/treehouse/giflib-hibernate/commit/f97a2828a466e849d8ae84884b5dce60a66cf412) for the github example.

Comment: Does the "new" way really needs to be that long in compare to the old one?

Answer (score 4):

```
public List<Service> getServiceAll(){
     return ServiceDaoImpl.getSession().createCriteria(Service.class).list();
}
```

Comment: even better from createQuery("from Product p");

Answer (score 3):

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

```
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    /* Selecting all objects(records) start_______________________ */



    Query qry = session.createQuery("from Product p");

    List l =qry.list();
    System.out.println("Total Number Of Records : "+l.size());
    Iterator it = l.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Object o = (Object)it.next();
        Product p = (Product)o;
        System.out.println("Product id : "+p.getProductId());
        System.out.println("Product Name : "+p.getProName());
        System.out.println("Product Price : "+p.getPrice());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }       

    session.close();
    factory.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the native query

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            List<Book> bookList = session.createNativeQuery("Select * from book", Book.class).getResultList();
            return bookList;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).